# Is there a term for opposite words that can be used to mean the same thing?

Tags: phrases, expressions, antonyms, semantics

For example

- "1 in 20 Americans suffer from..." and "1 out of 20 Americans suffer from..."
- "it is down to you" and "it is up to you"

They seem like great ways to add to creative writing.

Is there a specific term for these words? (like homonym, heteronym, etc)

Comment: *It is down to you* and *It is up to you* don't mean the same thing at all. *Down to you* means all other have been eliminated leaving only you.  *Up to you* means the decision is yours (regardless of how that was achieved).

Comment: You've got two chances of having this question survive on EL&U: fat and slim.

Comment: @Jim: He could(n't) care less.

Comment: See [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76104/what-is-the-difference-between-its-up-to-you-and-its-down-to-you). It was the hottest question on stackexchange for a while, too

Comment: @asymptotically thanks for the link. I don't see my question making it to quite that status ;)

Comment: @Jim why is it that it won't survive?

Comment: @John - Jim probably feels, as I do too, that the question is open-ended and has no definitive single answer.

Comment: I agree with @Ste. I voted to close this question because we generally discourage list-type questions as they give no definitive answers.

Comment: We are looking for thoughtful, intriguing questions posed as you would ask them of an expert, including evidence that you have put effort and research into the question. Please edit to share the results of your research.

Comment: The question has fundamentally changed, I'm not sure that's kosher, might have been better to leave this list-question and closed and started a fresh post, but either way the short answer to the updated question is ***contranyms***. Not sure that covers prepositional phrases like "in" vs "out of" or idioms like "fat chance" vs "slim chance", but it certainly does cover word pairs like "bad" and "good" both meaning "impressive".

Comment: Voted to reopen this 6-year-old question simply because its 6-year-old edit made it eligible for @DanBron's 6-year-old comment-as-answer (preferably working in the obvious Run D.M.C. quote).

Comment: In support of Dan Bron: 75 Contronyms (Words with Contradictory Meanings) - https://www.dailywritingtips.com/75-contronyms-words-with-contradictory-meanings/