# be down to -infinitive without to

Tags: grammar

I've consulted different dictionaries but I've not found the usage of this structure like in the following example:
''I'm down to sell records but not my soul''
is it slang? What does it exactly means?

Comment: Without further context, it's hard to be sure, as 'down', 'put down', 'put someone down', 'put something down, 'put someone down to' and 'put something down to' have a wide variety of meanings. I'd guess at sense 4a given by Macmillan [here](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/put-down): ... this meaning of **put down**
4 [TRANSITIVE] to write someone's name on a list, especially so that they can take part in something
put someone down to do something: I've put you down to help with the food. [and then **you'd** say _'I'm down to ...'_ ]

Comment: No, that's not what I meant... The meaning I can infer from the example I wrote is that the speaker is committed to selling records... is it right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "it's up to you" and "it's down to you"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76104/what-is-the-difference-between-its-up-to-you-and-its-down-to-you)

Comment: It's not a usage I'm familiar with, and I haven't found it in any of the dictionaries I've checked in. It does sound like slang.

Comment: @FF No; different structure (OP's has an agent, or rather 'responsible person', subject).

Comment: @Edwin: I think OP's usage is a "not-very-common" derivative of the standard *"I've signed up/put my name down to do **this**, but I won't do **that**!"* I'd expect it to be covered *somewhere* in that earlier question.

Comment: @FF Didn't spot it.

Comment: Here is the like http://rapgenius.com/50-cent-patiently-waiting-lyrics#note-1631878

Comment: @Edwin: There's little difference between *"It's down to me"* (I'm responsible) and *"I'm down for it"* (I agree/want to do it).

Comment: Here is the link to the song where I found it http://rapgenius.com/50-cent-patiently-waiting-lyrics#note-1631878

Comment: @gio: Note that rap singers are particularly keen on the word "down", and they're not renowned for "careful, accurate, standard" use of language. But most likely in this case it's just a reversal of the standard idiom *"I'm **up** for it"* - meaning, *"I agree/want to do it"*.

Comment: @FF Except that "I'm down for it" seems absent from dictionaries I've found containing "It's down / up to me" and "(informal) I'm up for it".

Comment: The only source I've found until now is a bilingual dictionary (english-italian) and the translation would be 'be determined to'. here the link, just in case you'd like to see http://www.wordreference.com/enit/be%20down%20to

Comment: [Here](http://www.independent.co.uk/voices/columnists/miles-kington/an-english-lesson-if-you-are-up-for-it-529293.html) is Miles Kington's 2005 judgement: '... Of course, you cannot always expect things to be so neat. When we say "It's up to you", the other person can respond by saying "I'm up for it". But if we say "It's down to you", the other person cannot say "I'm down for it".

Answer (score 2):

You're looking in the wrong place for the wrong thing, so no wonder you're not finding it.
Dictionaries won't tell you the [metaphor themes](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf).

This *down* is certainly part of a construction, and there are a **lot** of constructions that use *down.*
Most of these constructions use one of [the many metaphoric senses of `Up/Down`](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/125538/15299).

So, in this particular case, ***I'm down to `VP`*** can come from at least the following constructions:

- *I am down on the list of people who `VP`.*
  i.e, my name is written on that list, implying that I must `VP`
  (this is the *down* of the phrasal verb *write down*)
- *I am down for the purpose of `VP`-ing.*
  i.e, I came down for that purpose, implying I am higher in authority than my addressee(s)
  (this is a physical locative *down*, where *down (here)* represents a place)

With a gerund instead of an infinitive, however, one can access status `Up/Down`

- *I am down to `VP`-ing (again).*
  i.e, my status is at low ebb (this is the *down* of *down to seeds and stems*)

Go for [the metaphors](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/April05Eye.pdf).

Comment: May I ask what metaphor is used here: `I'm down on the concept of literature`?

Comment: _(Be) down on `X`_ makes use of the `Up Is Good/Down Is Bad` theme. The subject must be a sentient animate noun phrase, and the construction expresses the distaste of the subject for `X`, which must be a noun phrase, but may be either a gerund or an embedded question complement clause, like _I'm down on skiing_ or _She's down on whatever he suggests_.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's a variation on the informal idiom "[down with](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71491/whats-the-origin-of-im-down-with-it)", "down to {infinitive}" being equivalent to "down with {gerund}".  I can't find much in the way of citations to support  this contention, but it seems to fit better than the more common senses of "down to" such as "attributable to" (*e.g.,* "The great number of potholes this hear is down to the frequent snows.")  or "connected to" (*e.g.,* "She's a down to Earth person."), or some of the less savory senses of "down".

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely slang. It's similar to [this](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=i%27m%20down) urban dictionary entry. The infinitive would most likely be something like "(to) be down". When you say you are *down with* something, it means you are *okay with it* or you have no reservations/inhibitions against it.

Answer (score 0):

It's obviously a musician saying he's willing and eager to sell records but not his soul.

As to structure, yeah, it's slang.

Comment: I'll add, to say that you're "down" to doing something is an old-fashioned expression. Usually like, I'm down to do this but not that. A slang variation of "put me down for ... "